# R: what is the difference between rm and remove?

Tags: r

What is the difference between [`rm` and `remove`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rm.html)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no difference; `remove` is an alias and is defined as:

```
remove <- rm
```

See the source code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/rm.R)

Comment: +1 for the benefit of OP: you can also see this with `body(rm) == body(remove)`

Comment: Similar to Matthew's comment:  typing `rm` and `remove` return identical code to the console.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Here is a contrived exception to that rule: `x <- 10; f1 <- local({x <- 2; function() x}); f2 <- function() x`.  `body(f1) == body(f2)` is `TRUE` but the functions are effectively "different" and `f1()` returns a different value than `f2()`

Comment: @GSee That's a good point. It's easy to forget that functions are more than they just their definitions in R. I suppose `identical(environment(rm), environment(remove)) & identical(body(rm), body(remove)) & identical(formals(rm), formals(remove))` would be the truely correct way. Looks like this answer is turning into a nice little cash cow for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

They are identical now, but if I remember correctly (and this may have only been in S+) it used to be that `rm` removed the elements specified without quotes and `remove` required quotes or a variable with a list of the objects to remove.  So `rm` would be used in the same way that both are mostly used today (without specifying any arguments) and `remove` would be used like `rm( list= ...` is today.  Since both are useful they were merged into `rm` a while back, but since people had used `remove` in the past it was made an alias for `rm`.

Comment: Well, it's been the way it is in R for at least [15 years](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/80135135fc0cdc8c2fea655200ee7183c9737a15/src/library/base/R/rm.R)

Comment: @GSee, the difference may have only been in S/S+, but R kept both names.  My first experience with a port of S was 26 years ago.  A lot of things have changed in that time.