# within.list() versus within.data.frame() - What's the difference?

Tags: r

Upon investigating `within()`, I noticed it uses methods for lists and data frames.

```
within
# function (data, expr, ...) 
# UseMethod("within")
# <bytecode: 0x4403f78>
# <environment: namespace:base>
methods("within")
# [1] within.data.frame within.list      
# see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Reading through the code for each `within.list()` and `within.data.frame()`, I noticed they are exactly the same. This is confirmed by

```
identical(within.list, within.data.frame)
# [1] TRUE
```

They also seem to act the same, and do exactly the same thing.  Take these two examples:

```
x <- list(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
identical(
    within.list(x, { d <- 11:15 }), 
    within.data.frame(x, { d <- 11:15 }) 
)
# [1] TRUE
y <- as.data.frame(x)
identical(
    within.list(y, { d <- 11:15 }),
    within.data.frame(y, { d <- 11:15 })
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Is there an actual difference between these two functions?  If so, what is it?  If not, why do two of exactly the same function exist?

Comment: [`rm`/`remove`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17299128) is another example of a function with two names, but the reason behind it is different (historical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference. `within.list` is an alias for `within.data.frame`.  See [the source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/776708efe6003e36f02587ad47b2eaaaa19e2f69/src/library/base/R/eval.R)

```
within.list <- within.data.frame
```

Both exist so that if the `within` generic is called on either a `list` or a `data.frame` the proper method will be dispatched.

If `within.list` didn't exist and you tried to call `within(myList, ...)` you would get an error like

```
Error in UseMethod("within") : 
  no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Comment: Interesting...but the methods are both the same. And a data frame is a list.  So wouldn't `within.list` suffice for both? Or is it just a formality thing?

Comment: Note that `class(data.frame())` does not include `"list"`